# Access Control Lists & Access Control Objects, good tutorial?

Tags: permissions, acl

we're developing a web app to cover all aspects of a printing company from finances, to payroll, to job costing.  Its important to be able to control who can access what parts of these applications.  Don't want a line employee giving himself a raise, etc...

I've heard of the concept of ACL & ACO, but haven't found a good example that we could adapt to our project.

Anyone know where I can find good information to work from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brief rundown on ACLs, where they should be used and how they should be structured and implemented for various applications and user levels can be found here:

[LINK](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AccessControlList)

Answer (score 1):

I've had to implement that type of security a couple of times.  Unfortunately I don't know of any really good articles that provide examples.  My implementations were mainly piecing together the parts through trial and error.

However, I did come across this link on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52kd59t0(VS.71).aspx

It has some of the concepts.

---

After my original post, I did some more research.  I found this article:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Implementing-Role-Based-Security-using-CSharp/

it seems pretty promising, I didn't go through all the details, but it at least guides you through the high-level topics.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET/Windows you might want to look into Windows Authorization Manager (AzMan). There are support for AzMan in Enterprise Library but there are other ways of using it as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998336.aspx
http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/WhatIsAuthorizationManager.html